# Size of two joined tables in SQL with primary key

Tags: sql, database, join, primary-key

I want to know if joining a table that has a primary key `x` with another table, tells us anything about the size of the resulting table, in instance consider the following query:

```
SELECT r.*,s.* FROM r, s WHERE r.a = s.x;
```

`r`and `s`are two arbitrary tables that contain respectively `n` and `m` tuples. If we consider `x` as a primary key of `s` does it change our perspective about the size of their join? or would it always vary between `0`, if `a`and `x`are never equal, and `n`(or `m`) if `a` and `x` are identical.

Comment: How are you measuring size? number of resulting rows, bytes, number of resulting columns? Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Also, please use modern JOIN syntax, available since SQL-92.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the number of resulting rows and columns.

Comment: 1) The number of columns is easy: it's the sum of the the columns of both tables. 2) The number of rows, however, depends on the data; ask yourself: Are there rows that match the join predicate? The resulting number of rows can be anything between `0` to `n x m`.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the resulting join for your scenario would be between 0 and less than or equal to the sum(size of table r + size of table s). The individual table sizes is typically average row length * number of rows/tuples.

Comment: Does adding a primary key to one of the tables has any effect on the size of the resulting table? I mean can it help us narrowing its size?

Comment: If.you have the joining column as primary key in the two tables you ensure that you have 1-1 relationship which controls the number of rows. The size of a row is dependent on the columns you select. The combination of these two give you the final size. If this was useful pls do accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT r.*, s.*
FROM r JOIN
     s 
     ON r.a = s.x;
```

If `x` is a primary key in `s`, then it is never duplicated.  Obviously, the query can return zero rows.  What is the maximum?

Well, each `x` is unique.  Each row in `r` can match at most one row in `s`.  So, an upper limit is the number of rows in `r`.  Because `a` is not a primary key in `r`, it can be repeated.  All rows in `r` can have the same value.

So, the number of rows returned is between 0 and the number of rows in `r`.